# What are the default control settings for the function DocumentTermMarix from the package tm?

Tags: r, tokenize, tm

When I investigated the resulting dtm matrices, I discovered that tokens were lowercased unless the setting was set to False. Furthermore, words with underscores were split before tokenization.

When I looked up the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-1/topics/TermDocumentMatrix) I was not able to retrieve the default settings, or what settings were used if no explicit control was provided.

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `DocumentTermMatrix` says "see `termFreq` for available local control options."

If you do:

```
?termFreq
```

you'll see all the possible options with the defaults (which includes the "Defaults to `tolower`" you are referring to).

Comment: OP, be aware that you reference one function in the title of the post (DocumentTermMatrix), yet you provide a link to the documentation of another function (TermDocumentMatrix).

Comment: Thanks. I agree that it was sloppy of me not to see this, but I will leave the question here (unless too many vote to delete it) because this is what shows up if you google "r tm Term-Document Matrix default settings" which might be useful to some.